# Rank A st $ a_{ij}=i +j $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the $n \times n$ matrix such that $a_{ij}=i +j $. Find rank of $A$

My attempt: taking examples for the $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ cases, I see the rank is $n$. Is this generally true?

Comment: Are you sure about the $3\times 3$ case?

Comment: sorry for 3 x 3 its not 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not $n$ when $n>2$. Here's a hint: Row $i-1$ subtracted from Row $i$ results in $[1,1,\ldots,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Agree. Because subtraction the first line from second, third and so on until $n-th$ we get the following matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & ... & n+1 \\
1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
1 & 1 & ... & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So its rank is 2, $n\ge 3$.