# rank of given nxn matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

P 1 Let A and B n x n matrices each having rank n. Find the rank of $ A^3B^2A $.

P 2 let A=($ a_{ij}$) be n xn matrix st  $ a_{ij}=min (i, j)$ . Find rank of A.

My attempt 
for P2
Its 3x3 and 2x2 case hve rank n. Can we generalise it to have rank n?

For p1, I think$ A^3B^2A $ will have rank n.
I need suggestion here.thanks

Comment: Do you know that a square $\;n\times n\;$ matrix $\;A\;$ has full rank iff $\;\det A\neq 0\;$ ? And do you know that in general for square matrices we have $\;\det(AB)=\det A\cdot\det B\;$?

Comment: O yes I think this is for p1. Thank you sir

Comment: For Part (2), why don't you try applying the same idea you (hopefully) learned from your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134677/rank-a-st-a-ij-i-j)?

Comment: Part 2 here is little more tricker than previous one. So I asked again

Comment: Well again, subtract row $i-1$ from row $i$.

Comment: @s Not that much trickier. Read below.

Comment: An $n\times n$ matrix having rank $n$ is invertible. The product of invertible matrices is invertible. No need for determinants.

Comment: @egreg What proof do you know that "the product of invertible matrices is invertible" that doens't use determinants? This really interests me as one could approach this fact in a hopefully more basic fashion.

Comment: @Timbuc $(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})=I=(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)$. So $(AB)^{-1}$ exists and $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we already have P 1, and as for P 2: we in general have

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&\ldots&1\\1&2&2&\ldots&2\\1&2&3&\ldots &3\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\1&2&3&\ldots&n\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, reduce the above doing $\;R_i-R_1\;,\;\;i=2,3,...,n\;$ :

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&\ldots&1\\0&1&1&\ldots&1\\0&1&2&\ldots &2\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\0&1&2&\ldots&n-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Developing now the determinant of the above by the first column and using induction in an almost trivial fashion, you get the rank is ...

Comment: Determinant is non zero, rank is n.

Comment: @singularity Exactly so, doing the base cases $\;n=1,2\;$ or even $\;n=3\;$ .

Comment: By induction hypothesis, the matrix obtained after removing the first row and column has rank $n-1$. So the matrix has rank $n$. No determinant needed.

Comment: Well, also what egreg says as it is pretty obvious that the first row is linearly independent of all the rows below it in the reduced form. But since the OP already stated he knows about determinants...